# OpenCV - not able to grab all frames

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a very basic question about frame capturing using OpenCV. My code look like below:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cv::Mat mat;
int i = 0;
while(cap.read(mat)==true) {
    //some code here
    i = i + 1;
}
```

It works well. However, when I look at logcat logs by OpenCV, it says

FRAMES Received 225, grabbed 123.

and this grabbed (123) usually matches with the variable 'i' (number of loops) in my code.
Ideally my code should be able to read all received frames, isn't it? Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: What happens if you take out the '//some code here' code? How many frames are grabbed then?

Comment: Exactly, I tried that too :) and the above experiment is actually without any code. If I add "some code here", grabbed count decreases further e.g.41 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `cap.read(mat)` takes a certain amount of time as it has to obtain and decode the image's video feed and convert it to the `cv::Mat` format. This amount of time appears to be greater than the video's capture rate. You can determine the frames per second of the video capture with the following:

```
double frames_per_second = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

Try timing the amount of time your `cap.read(mat)` call takes and see if you can see a relationship between the ratio of frames received to frames grabbed and the ratio of the capture time (`1/frames_per_second`) and the time `cap.read(mat)` takes to execute.

Source:
http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ca/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html

Comment: Yes, frames_per_second prints 30 for me.